# Does a mundane weapon thrown with a magic ki focus return?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranged-attack, implements

For the classes proficient with them, the rules for the ki focus are as follows:

> **Ki Focuses and Weapon Attacks:** If you use a magic ki focus, you can add its enhancement bonus to the attack rolls and the damage rolls of weapon attacks you make using a weapon with which you have proficiency. If you have both a magic ki focus and a magic weapon, you choose before you use an attack power whether to draw on the magic of the ki focus or that of the weapon. Your choice determines which enhancement bonus, critical hit effects, and magic item properties and powers you can apply to that power. You can’t, for example, use the enhancement bonus of your ki focus and the critical hit effect of your magic weapon on the same attack.

Essentially, this appears to indicate (as does the online character builder) that you can essentially count any weapon used with a ki focus in this manner as being enchanted with the same enchantment as the ki focus you are applying to the attack.

The rules for magic weapons returning are as follows:

> Any magic light thrown or heavy thrown weapon, from the lowly +1 Dagger to the +6 Dragonslayer Javelin automatically returns to the wielder's hand after a Ranged Attack with the weapon is resolved.

**If I apply my ki focus to a mundane light or heavy thrown weapon, would the weapon return to me after the attack?**

I am assuming that the weapon would at least have the benefits of the ki focus enchantment for the duration of the attack, and that if I had even the simplest [Magic Weapon +1](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1774) enchantment it would return regardless.

**For example, would I need to throw an additional mundane dagger each time I attack, or can I throw one repeatedly and have it magically return after each attack?**

Answer (score 4):

**No, they do not.**

Mundane thrown weapons **do not** return to your hand like magic ones do. A ki focus does not make the weapon you throw magic; it merely adds its enhancement bonus to your attack and damage rolls (and you get its critical hit effects, properties etc).

You also technically need one dagger/hammer/javelin/etc. for each target of each attack for an entire encounter. However, much like ammo, this is rarely tracked. It should be noted that you do automatically collect your expended thrown weapons after each encounter.

**One easy way around this:** When level 1 weapon enchantments become quite cheap (around level 5), buy the Magic Weapon +1 thrown weapons you need because they will automatically return when used with a ki focus.